# How do I prove that the layered vector product A × [B × (C × D)] = B[A · (C × D)] − (A · B)(C × D)?

Tags: vectors

Given the layered quadruple vector product A × [B × (C × D)] and by using simple vector identities prove it is equal to B[A · (C × D)] − (A · B)(C × D).

I attempted to use the vector triple product to get A × [C(B · D) - D(B · C)], then I distributed A into the product to get (A × C)(B · D) - (A × D)(B · C), but I do not know how to proceed from there. I am also unsure if A × [B × (C × D)] is equal to (A × B) × (C × D), which is listed as an important identity on Wikipedia. It appears that I am now in a dead end. Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_calculus_identities#Addition_and_multiplication

Answer (score 1):

You just need to use $A\times(B\times E)=(A\cdot E)B-(A\cdot B)E$, with $E=C\times D$

Comment: As a follow up question is A × [B × (C × D)] = (A × B) × (C × D), through some form of rearrangement or does parentheses order matter for a quadruple vector product?

Comment: No, I don't think these are equal; if you take $A=B=C=\vec{i}$ and $D=\vec{j}$, I think you'll see that these give different values.